# form needs to be submitted twice before sending updated data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, blogs

so basic outline...

I have 'posts' pulled from the database and displayed like so:

```
<div class="blogtest">

    <form action="process/updatepost.php" class="updatepost" method="post">
        <input type="button" class='.$editenabled.' value="Edit">
        <input type="submit" class="saveupdatebutton" value="Save">
        <input type="hidden" class="postid" name="postid" value="'.$postID.'">

        <div class="text">

            <div class="buildtext">'.$text.'</div>

            <div class="editor"><textarea name="ckeditor"id="ckeditor" class="ckeditor">'.$text.'</textarea></div>

        </div>

    </form>

    </div>
```

Once the edit button is clicked, the buildtext class hides and the ckeditor is shown. Same for the edit and save button.

When save is clicked, a ajax call is made and then the data is updated. This works perfectly fine... however it only works perfectly fine if there is only 1 blog post on that page.

Here is the ajax for reference:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".updatepost").submit(function(){
    var $targetForm = $(this);

    $targetForm.find(".error").remove();
    $targetForm.find(".success").remove();

    // If there is anything wrong with 
    // validation we set the check to false
    var check = true;

    // Get the value of the blog update post
    var $ckEditor = $targetForm.find('.ckeditor'),
        blogpost = $ckEditor.val();

            // Validation
    if (blogpost == '') {
        check = false;
       $ckEditor.after('<div class="error">Text Is Required</div>');
    }

      // ... goes after Validation
    if (check == true) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process/updatepost.php",
    data: $targetForm.serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){

    if (response.databaseSuccess)
       $targetForm.find(".error").remove();
    else
       $ckEditor.after('<div class="error">Something went wrong!</div>');

}
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

So, if there is 2 blog posts on the page and i edit the 2nd (last) post, on clicking save the post is updated correctly.

However if i edit any other then it takes two submits for the data to be sent.

I checked on firebug and it shows that on the first click, the old value is sent, and then on the 2nd the new one.

Where am i going wrong?

Eventually (once working) the post will be refreshed on the success of the ajax call but for now its obviously vital that the user only has to click save once.

Thanks for any help! Any more code needed and ill post it here.

Craig :)

EDIT: After making ckeditor just a normal textarea it works fine. Must be ckeditor not updating as i know it doesnt litrally work as a textarea as such. Maybe ill have to use another rich editor...

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem.  Just to share my experience in case anyone ends up here with the same issue.  The CKEditor wasn't updating the target textarea on the first click on the submit button and since I had data validation on the text area thankfully made me aware that the textarea wasn't being populated on the first submit.  To overcome this I add this bit of code:

```
$('#accept-button').click(function (event) {
    for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly in my case.
I'm using Ajax for submitting the content of the form so I could run the for loop right before posting.

`$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

 for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
  CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement();
 }

 $.post(baseUrl, $(this).serialize(), function(object) {
  alert('Content saved!');
 });
});`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from the [integration guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter), CKEditor most probably uses its own onsubmit event to actually send data back to the textarea. This would mean that those 2 events might fire up reversed order, first retrieving the old text from your code and only then updating the textarea.

You can always try and retrieve CKEditor's content using the following syntax:

```
var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.getData();
```

Also, are you using the jQuery adapter with CKEditor?

**EDIT**: the problem seems to be having same IDs on multiple textareas, all being called "ckeditor". This would result in unexpected behaviour across browsers, since ID must be always unique to a page.

Comment: i have seen that part of code floating around but never seems to work / i cant understand it.

Here the normal that i use:

 var $ckEditor = $targetForm.find('ckeditor'),
         blogpost = $ckEditor.val();

are you able to create something from that which might help me understand it?

Comment: how do you create CKEditor instances? do they all have different custom IDs or they are all called "ckeditor"?

Comment: all called ckeditor because they are echoed out from the database in a foreach

Comment: ah, that would be a problem - element ID must be unique to the page, so they must all have different IDs (the classname can be the same - ckeditor, but ID must be different)

Comment: Thanks for the help, after playing about and using some maths to give each editor it's own id number all works :)

Comment: excellent, glad you could resolve the issue :) would you mind voting the answer up and accepting it if you found it helpful please? :)